# Why is this css example behaving this way?

Tags: html, css

Why is this simple html/css not behaving the way I expect?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <header>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="site.css">
    </header>
    <body>
        <div id="file-explorer"></div>
        <div id="file-queue"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 2rem;
    background-color:blue;
}

#file-explorer {
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: red;
}

#file-queue {
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Question:

First of all, I don't understand how a body tag can receive a margin param. It can't grow outside the viewport. Shouldn't only padding be valid for body?. I have used padding but I get same result.

On the other hand, I am using box-sizing = border-box. So, the size I'm providing should contain margins/paddings/border. Therefore, if I say I want my two divs to be 50% of viewport why am I getting a result bigger than the viewport (as you can see a vertical scroll box is shown)?

I expected to have a margin around both divs and all fitting exactly in the browser viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not setting the height and the wanted gap the way it should.

- Use for `height` `%` percentage and it will follow the box-sizing you did set , *(`vh/vw/vmin/vmax` are using the viewport sizes)*.
- Use `padding` instead `margin` and it will follow the box-sizing you set *(`padding` and `border` are included into calculation if set to `border-box`, not `margin`)*.

fixed example if that helps you:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  padding: 2rem;
  height: 100vh;/* vh here is okay */
  background-color: blue;
}

body {
  height: 100%;/* it will use the 100% of height avalaible inside the border and padding of the parent */
}

#file-explorer {
  height: 50%;/* half-height of the parent, not the viewport */
  background-color: red;
}

#file-queue {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="site.css">
</header>

<body>
  <div id="file-explorer"></div>
  <div id="file-queue"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> First of all, I don't understand how a body tag can receive a margin
> param. It can't grow outside the viewport. Shouldn't only padding be
> valid for body?. I have used padding but I get same result.

body tag is also one of tags. So it is in html tag. body tag is expanded on screen without any style. When it gets margin, then body tag is shrunk for the thickness which is same as margin size.

> On the other hand, I am using box-sizing = border-box. So, the size
> I'm providing should contain margins/paddings/border. Therefore, if I
> say I want my two divs to be 50% of viewport why am I getting a result
> bigger than the viewport (as you can see a vertical scroll box is
> shown)?

vh is a relative unit. When the rates are 100% then there is no place for margin. So margin should be in the vh too like the example below.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {    
    margin: 10vh;
    background-color:blue;
}

#file-explorer {
    height: 40vh;
    background-color: red;
}

#file-queue {
    height: 40vh;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <header>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="site.css">
    </header>
    <body>     
        <div id="file-explorer"></div>
        <div id="file-queue"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```